# How to write your own simple constraint function in core.logic?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I just read the [primer](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/wiki/A-Core.logic-Primer) for core.logic. It makes sense so far, but I'm not sure where to go to learn more.

Let's say I wanted to write my own constraint, sort of like the `membero` shown in the primer. This one is called `vectoro` and constrains things to be a vector.

```
(defn vectoro [s] ???)

(run* [q]
  (conde
    [(== q [1 2])]
    [(== q :a)])
  (vectoro q))
```

Now I want that to return `[1 2]`. How do you write `vectoro`? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a core.logic [`pred`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.logic/pred) macro that makes this easy:

```
(run* [q]
  (== q [1 2])
  (pred q vector?))
=> ([1 2])

(run* [q]
  (== q '(1 2))
  (pred q vector?))
=> ()
```

Here's how you might define a `vectoro` function/contraint (but realize this is [essentially the exact same thing `pred` is doing](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/4b576599cf46b6c8d37f819dd8832d8631aaad17/src/main/clojure/cljs/core/logic.clj#L173-L177)):

```
(defn vectoro [a]
  (project [a]
    (== true (vector? a))))
```

`project` is used to operate on the actual/concrete *value* of the logic variable (`LVar`). We can then use the plain old predicate `vector?` and require the result be true. This also works with your example program:

```
(run* [q]
  (conde
    [(== q [1 2])]
    [(== q :a)])
  (vectoro q))
=> ([1 2])

(run* [q]
  (conde
    [(== q '(1 2))]
    [(== q :a)])
  (vectoro q))
=> ()
```

Answer (score 1):

To continue learning, I suggest looking for [projects that use core.logic](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=extension%3Aclj+core.logic&repo=&start_value=1&type=Code) and seeing if their source code teaches you anything.

As for your specific question about `vectoro`, the "[project](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/44cf5a700afb57d7193c7592bcd2921815d01798/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/logic.clj#L1327-L1334)" function (as in "projection") will probably accomplish what you want, something along the lines of

```
(defn vectoro [s v]
  (core.logic/project [v]
    (core.logic/== s (vector? v)))
```